# firebase retrieve nodes with null field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I updated the domain classes of my project and some incompabilities happened with the previous versions...

I'm getting rid of most of them but there is one situation that is problematic

I need to find all firebase nodes, from one specific branch, which a specif field == null

Let me explain the background:
I added some new fields in my domain classes to store in firebase... so all data previously stored will have `null` values for these fields, i want to retrieve these nodes... is there a simple way (PLEASE, WITHOUT DUMP THE WHOLE DATABASE)

here is my schema:

```
root
-users
--a
---newField
/*many other irrelevant fields*/ 
--b
---newField
//so on and so on
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
App.getDatabaseInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("newField").equalTo(null).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

But it always return empty and i know there are some nodes with this situation.

Is there any way to achieve my intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query the database for children that don't exist. But what you can do is to remove your `equalTo(null)` statement and you will get your result sorted with the data that is missing the `newField` child first. Iterate over the result set until you reach an entry that already has the `newField` set, that means that you've already processed all the data that **didn't** have it.

Please see this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key

> Any node which does not have the child key we're querying on is sorted with a value of null, meaning it will come first in the ordering. For details on how data is ordered, see the [How Data is Ordered section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-ordered-data).

Comment: To limit the amount of data that is retrieved, be sure to `ref.orderBy("newField").endAt("\t")`. Here `\t` is the tab character, which is just a character very early in the ASCII chart. By ending the results there, you're reducing the number of items that are returns.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, so in firebase terms using `.endAt("\t")` is the same as something like:  `.equalTo(null or "\t")`?

Comment: I just read the article mentioned by @Dennis answer and the optimal way is to add `endAt(false)`, this will return only the nodes with values for that field like null or false, the answer of @Frank does consider my field is a string when instead it is an integer